# Google map markers appearing on wrong location on the map

Tags: javascript, android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been working on an android application featuring google maps, I am requesting for coordinates to a node js server and the response is then parsed to double type and when passed to an object of Marker the marker appears on an inaccurate location, I have copied the coordinates from the database and when I pass them direct to the Marker's object, the marker appears on the right location, I also have an alert box displaying the value of the markers as I receive them from the serve and it seems to be displaying the right coordinates, what I think is there is some garbage value with in the variables to which I assign the coordinates or it can be an issue in parsing while i get them in the form of JSON from the server and parse them to double
I have done a little search but I couldn't find a solution specifically addressing my issue, if I haven't been thorough I am sorry, thank you all in advance for your help.

**Here is the code:**
The code when I receive the coordinates and parse them (via socketIO):

```
public void on(String functionName, IOAcknowledge ioAck, Object... arguments) {

                if("points_of_interest".equals(functionName)){

                temp=arguments[0].toString();
                try {
                    JSONObject object=new JSONObject(temp);
                    String idStop=object.getString("route_id");
                    String longt=object.getString("stop_longg");
                    String lat=object.getString("stop_lat");

                    lati=Double.parseDouble(lat);
                    lngi=Double.parseDouble(longt);



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                                 }
                            }
```

**Now here is the function call that creates the markers in the onCreate method:**

```
      map=((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.allBusMaps)).getMap();


     createStops();
```

Here is the code for createStops() method:

```
     public void createStops(){

     map.clear();
//   LatLng lhr=new LatLng(31.500794,74.316777);
             LatLng lhr=new LatLng(lati,lngi);



    Marker lahore = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lhr).title("busStop"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lhr, 15));

 }
```

**In the above mentioned case case when I am passing the value through variables this is the output being generated:**

But when I pass the values direct to the Marker's object the marker appears on the right locations:

e.g.     LatLng lhr=new LatLng(31.500794,74.316777);

Comment: what are the values you are getting from json for lati,lngi variables?

Comment: Sir i have used an alert box to display the values of the lati,lngi variables and both are being displayed correctly 31.500794 and 74.316777 respectively

Comment: I think the issues lies with in the parsing

Comment: Look at the key you're retrieving your longitude with from the json. Is `stop_longg` correct? Are you outputting those two variables anywhere to see their values are being set correctly?

Comment: @DiscoS2 yes sir i m displaying them in a alert on a button click and the result is the correct one, do u think the parsing is ok?

Comment: also after repeated testing i have found out that, it works correct on a few attempts but then once u reinstall the app on the device it again gives the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the above problem i was having on repeated debugging,
the problem i noticed was that lati and lngi objects were not getting their respective values for a specified time interval, until which both of these objects remained to an initial value of 0.0 and 0.0 respectively hence on majority of test attempts the marker was not appearing at the accurate location.
To overcome this problem, i have enforced a wait of 500 milliseconds before i call the createStops method, that gives the lati and lngi objects sufficient time to attain their respective values from the server.
Here is what worked for me:

```
  map=((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.allBusMaps)).getMap();

    //new pointMarker().execute();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500); //a wait of 500 milliseconds
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    createStops(); // this is the method that creates the markers
```

Thank you everyone for your help.